# Need regulated 15 kV output

Tags: voltage-regulator, ltspice, spike, zvs

I was just playing around with this ZVS circuit I made in LTspice. It was made to output 15 kV, but when I saw its actual output it had spikes of 25 kV, then it stabilized after a while. How to prevent this misbehavior when making the actual circuit?

The circuit:

[image: The circuit diagram]

The output:

[image]

EDIT: I've already tried attaching an RC circuit to the 100 Ω resistors at the top but that delays the circuit powerup and the LC circuit won't resonate. The extra circuitry at the bottom (from Electroboom) just delays when the resonating stuff will happen, but still the spikes come. I've left it because it can be useful in the actual circuit. I've also tried putting very small capacitors and inductors at the final 1 MΩ load but that reduces the output voltage to 10 kV even if I use only one at a time, and the spikes are still there, at 15 kV.

Comment: You're talking about it as if you tried with an actual circuit. The simulation's fidelity won't be great since a lot of real parasitic effects are not captured in the schematic. And you'll want to measure the performance of the real circuit safely. So you should get a HV scope probe, actually build the circuit, and measure the results on the real circuit. I bet you won't have other problems with it, so the question is let's say premature? The gate drive waveform is also important to see, so you should show it on the same graph as the output voltage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of ZVS circuit is primitive and, I believe the problem you are seeing is due to it being a primitive circuit. When running normally you'd expect the primary current to rise and fall between a positive value (\$I+\$) and a negative value (\$I-\$) of current but, at start-up, the primary current starts at zero amps and rises (or falls depending on the first transistor to switch) to a value of either twice \$I+\$ or twice \$I-\$.

I suspect that this contributes in some part to excessive induction (and the higher-than-expected peak voltages in those first few cycles). Waveforms are needed to verify this and I encourage you to work at it more and add the primary current waveform to your question.

Comment: Can you help me with making this circuit not primitive?

Comment: Maybe there are variations of your ZVS circuit that can do this but, I'm not aware of one. If, on the other hand you are prepared to begin from scratch then a forward converter might be suitable. So might a resonant converter and even a flyback converter might do what you want. If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification @user012484